# Adding a decimal separator and two zeros after a single digit integer number in text

Tags: r, regex, string, replace

I have two variables as shown below:

```
x <- "3%-1ST $100000 AND 1.25% BALANCE"
y <- "3.22%-1ST $100000 AND 1.25% BALANCE"
```

What I want to do is adding `.00` to `3%` and change it to `3.00%` using regex; however, `3.22` should be intact and there is no need to change it (my main dataset has 50000 rows and these two are just an example)
I tried the code below first:

```
gsub("\\b(\\d)%\\b", "\\1\\.00%", x)
```

the result is shown below:

```
[1] "3%-1ST $100000 AND 1.25% BALANCE"
[2] "3.22%-1ST $100000 AND 1.25% BALANCE"
```

As you can see I was not successful to make the change. I tried another code without `\\b`. The result is shown below:

```
[1] "3.00%-1ST $100000 AND 1.25.00% BALANCE"
[2] "3.22.00%-1ST $100000 AND 1.25.00% BALANCE"
```

This result is also not acceptable as it changed 3.22. I guess having `\\b` is mandatory to define the boundary of the string; however, it doesn't work for some reason that I am not sure about. Can you please clarify how I can do this task and what's the problem with using `\\b`?

Comment: I'm not seeing \\b anywhere in your regex?

Comment: @Dubukay, sorry my bad! I fixed it. This is where I use `\\b`: `gsub("\\b(\\d)%\\b", "\\1\\.00%", x)`

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem: you ask why X does not do Y, while you just do not need X, you need something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```
x <- c("3%-1ST $100000 AND 1.25% BALANCE", 
       "3.22%-1ST $100000 AND 1.25% BALANCE", 
       "12.15% AND 5%")
```

Solution:

```
gsub("(?<!\\d\\.\\d)(\\d)(%)", "\\1.00\\2", x, perl = T)
[1] "3.00%-1ST $100000 AND 1.25% BALANCE" "3.22%-1ST $100000 AND 1.25% BALANCE" "12.15% AND 5.00%"
```

The solution lies not in using word boundaries but defining a negative condition on which the substitution is **not** to take place. That negative condition is implemented using negative lookbehind `(?<!...)`.

The lookbehind in more detail:

- `(?<!`: this initializes negative lookbehind, which is an instruction
  to match if to the left you do not see ...

  - `\\d`: a digit
  - `\\.`: a
    period
  - `\\d`: a digit
- `)`: this bracket concludes the negative lookbehind

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I understood most of the expression you wrote. Can you please explain what exactly `?<!` and  `(.*)` are doing in your code?

Comment: Have provided an explanation of the lookbehind. `(.*)`means 'anything occurring 0 or more times' and represents the third capturing group.

Comment: I've simplified the pattern (the third capturing group was not needed).